# why string.IsNullOrEmpty() is created?

Tags: c#, .net, string

If `string.Empty != null` why `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` is created?

I just want to say that:
if `null` and `string.Empty` are different to each other.

- why `string.IsNull();` and `string.IsEmpty();` separate methods does not exist.
- why a combined method `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` exists?

Comment: Because checking whether string contains at least one character or not is one of the most common things, so the .NET developers gave us nice shortcut.

Comment: I'm not happy with my formatting :( can anyone reformat it for me...

Comment: Reformat what exactly? Looks just fine to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- `string.IsNull` doesn't exist because you'd just check for the reference being null
- `string.IsEmpty` doesn't exist because you can easily compare for equality with "" or for a length of 0
- `string.IsNullOrEmpty` exists because it's simpler to write the single method call than use

  ```
     if (text == null || text.Length == 0)
  ```

  (or the inverse, of course).

Each of the individual checks can be done simply on its own, but it's convenient to have a combination of the two.

Comment: aahhhh, I don't know why these silly questions comes in my mind...:(  thanx @Jon for your answer;

Comment: And don't forget .NET 4 adds IsNullOrWhitespace. And this check is more than single line of code.

Comment: But when does one need such a function? I rarely encounter situations where one wants to treat `null` and `""` the same way. Encountering `null` usually implies a programming error and leads to `ArgumentNullException` and `""` can be bad user input which requires completely different behavior. And even if it's a bug it should throw something like `ArgumentException`

Comment: @Yet That question doesn't make much sense IMO. What kind of threading interference are you talking about? Strings are immutable, so once you've read the reference the output of this function is determined by the value of that reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's for checking that the input string is a valid one. (e.g, not null and not empty).
So you don't want to do both the checks each time you want to ensure that so that's why it is made for.
If you want to check either of the single ones you can just use the `== null` or `== ""` compares.